# Is it possible to print to pdf a wpf control no as image?

Tags: c#, wpf

To print a document to PDF, first a create an image from the view and I add this image to the fixed page. The code is the following:

```
    Size myPageSize = new Size(myView.Width, myView.Height);

    FixedDocument myDocument = new FixedDocument();
    myDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = miTamañoPagina;

    myView.Measure(myPageSize);
    myView.Arrange(new Rect(myPageSize));
    myView.UpdateLayout();

System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging
    .RenderTargetBitmap(794, 1122, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(myView);

System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
myImage.Source = bitmap;

    FixedPage miPage = new FixedPage();
    miPage.Width = myDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
    miPage.Height = myDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
    miPage.Children.Add(myImage);

    PageContent myContent = new PageContent();
    ((IAddChild)myContent).AddChild(miPage);
    myDocument.Pages.Add(myContent);

    System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog myDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
    if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        myDialog.PrintDocument(myDocument.DocumentPaginator, string.Empty);
    }
```

When I create a the PDF, it is like an imagen and I can't select the text, so I would like to know if there are any way to print the view without converting it to an image.

Actually I am using .net 4.7.2 and windows 10. I know that it there are a different behavior about grpahics between windows 7 and windows 8.1 and windows 10.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have noticed that I can use PrintVisual to print the view, the problem is that I need to print a background too, so if I add this code to my axml it doesn't print, but if I delete this code it prints.

```
<UserControl.Background>
        <ImageBrush AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Opacity="0.25" ImageSource="{Binding Source={x:Static vg:VariablesGlobales.Logo}}">
            <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75" CenterX=".5" CenterY="0.5" />
            </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </UserControl.Background>
```

When it prints, I can select the text.

So perhaps I should open another question asking how to print visual with a background image.

Comment: You'll have to print everything manually then (not as an image).

Comment: there would be a possible path WPF > WMF > PDF, here's what I found so far https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218036/1132334 but this involves external resources, probably commercial libraries, and is not guaranteed that you end up with selectable text.

Comment: Ia have realized that if I use PrintVisual(myView) it prints an empty pdf, but if I delete the background of the view, it prints correctly.